# Report Viewer in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

I am developing an application in C# (Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit) and I want to incorporate a display of reports that can be printed and can be exported to PDF or Excel.

The problem is that the project running on .NET Framework 2.0 (need to be supported for Windows 2000, XP or minimum), and the Report Viewer and loses its consistency.

What version of Report Viewer must be installed to suit the Visual Studio 2015 and .NET Framework can work in 2.0? It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005 installed.

You can download and install it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916